# How can I pass an argument to a function from a drop down in tkinter GUI

Tags: python, tkinter

## I have a function

```
def hist(x):
plotly.offline.plot( {
'data' : [{
    'type' : 'histogram',
    'x' : data[x],
}],
"layout": Layout(title=x)
})

hist("price")#function call
```

## in place of price i want the user to select other options in drop-down of tkinter gui and it should get updated in function call how should i proceed.

and also how to set a background image for a tkinter window which fits all the window irrespective of the dimensions of the window.

Comment: Do you have a GUI already? If not, I'd just use a some premade tkinter code like [easygui](http://easygui.sourceforge.net/tutorial.html#letting-the-user-select-from-a-list-of-choices).

Comment: I think this question's considered to be too broad for stackoverflow, see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: See [`tkinter`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/tkinter/info) tag info for more resources, tutorials etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using an `OptionMenu` widget from tkinter.

Essentially all we need to do is initialise the `OptionMenu` widget and then call it's `StringVar` variable.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def command():
    print(var.get())

var = StringVar(root)
var.set("Price")

option = OptionMenu(root, var, "Price", "Foo", "Bar")
option.pack()

button = Button(root, text="Ok", command=command)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

The above will create an `OptionMenu` and a `Button` and print the value of the `OptionMenu` whenever the `Button` is pressed.

---

Once you understand the base concepts at play here you can start getting *"fancy"* with how your inputting information.

We can set up a `trace` on the `StringVar` variable and use it to detect when the `OptionMenu` is updated, meaning we get an automatic response in the program without the user having to press a button after selecting something from the drop down.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def command(*args):
    print(var.get())

var = StringVar(root)
var.set("Price")

option = OptionMenu(root, var, "Price", "Foo", "Bar")
option.pack()

var.trace("w", command)

root.mainloop()
```